# Ubuntu Server keeps suspending when external monitor is disconnected

Tags: server, display, monitor

I got Ubuntu server 18.04.1 running on a laptop with a broken display. Obviously, I Used an external monitor for the install

Now when I disconnected the external monitor, the server suspends within seconds.

I tried to prevent that by masking sleep.target, hypernate.taget, suspend.target, and  hybrid-sleep.target.

This worked. It does not suspend :-) But... :-(
Now it is filling the logs with about messages 100 messages per second that it can not suspend causing one of the cores running 100%. Again only when the monitor is disconnected.

The laptop lid is still open but eventually, I like it to be closed while the server is still running.

Someone suggested the defective display could be sending some malfunctioned messages to the System, So I disconnected its connector from the mainboard.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I see this is an old question already but I experienced exactly the same problem. Moreover I was working on an embedded pc, which for some reason also thought it was a laptop and was receiving the lidswitch=closed signal continuously.

For me the following fixed the problem:

edit: `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`

Uncomment and change the line:

```
#HandleLidSwitch=suspend
```

to:

```
HandleLidSwitch=ignore
```

And restart logind with:

```
sudo service systemd-logind restart
```

This solved it for me, no more suspends and no more log flooding!